# hi i am new to react native i need to create a TextInput dynamically when clicking on create button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i need to generate text input dynamically every time a user clicks on the create button in react native using flatlist and using functional based component I am still very new to native

I do have idea how to do it in reactjs but there is less example for native

Comment: Can you share your idea with ReactJS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The FlatList takes an array as input so you can just add a value (probably a key or something) to the array every time you press the button and then render an Input for every value in the array